# Is there anything wrong with this proof of chain rule?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Is there anything wrong with this proof of the Chain Rule?

$$\begin{align}
(f(g(x)))'&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}\tag{eq 1}\\
g'(x) &= \lim _{h\to 0} 
\frac{g(x+h))-g(x)}{h}\\
g'(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0} h &= \lim _{h\to 0}\,(g(x+h)-g(x))\\
g'(x)\cdot\lim _{h\to 0} h + \lim _{h\to 0} g(x) &= \lim _{h\to 0} g(x+h)\\
\lim _{h\to 0} g(x+h)) &= g'(x)\cdot \lim _{h\to 0} h + \lim _{h\to 0} g(x)\tag{eq 2}
\end{align}$$

Substitute Equation 2 into Equation 1:
$$
\begin{align}
(f(g(x)))'&=\lim _{h\to 0}
\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}\\
&=\lim _{h\to 0} \frac{f(g'(x)\cdot h + g(x))-f(g(x))}{h}
\end{align}$$

Let $g'(x)\cdot h = h'$.
$$\begin{align}
\lim _{h'\to 0}
\frac{f(g'(x)\cdot h+ g(x))-f(g(x)))}{h}
&=\lim _{h'\to 0} \frac{
f(h' + g(x))-f(g(x))}{h}\\
&=g'(x)\cdot\lim _{h'\to 0}
\frac{f(h'+g(x))-f(g(x))}{g'(x)h}\\
&= g'(x)\cdot\lim_{h'\to 0}
\frac{f(h'+g(x))-f(g(x))}{h'}\\
&= g'(x) f'(g(x))
\end{align}$$

Hence $\;(f(g(x)))' = g'(x) f'(g(x))$

Comment: Although some things are understood, it would be nice if you could fixed MathJax to your post to help us with the reading. On the other hand, have you checked out the proof on this fundamental fact in a textbook? This is a classic result.

Comment: This is the proof my professor gave. But my problem with this proof is lim f(x)/g(x) = lim f(x)/lim g(x) only if limg(x) is not equal 0

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How to do subscript?

Comment: `$\lim_{h\to 0}$`

Comment: @BryanFoongZhiChuan I have edited the first two lines, you can finish editing your post using them as guides for the instructions. If you need help, you can tell me. Nice to help.

Comment: @BryanFoongZhiChuan . From your 1st comment I think I gather what your question is: seems like you think we can take the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h' + g(x))-f(g(x))}{g'(x)h}$ only when $\lim_{h\to 0}g(x)h$ is not equal to $0$. If that were true we could not even define the derivative of $f$ .

Comment: $g'(x) \lim_{h \to 0} h = \lim_{h \to 0} (g(x+h)-g(x))$ is just the equation $0=0$ (if $g$ is continuous at $x$). It's not useful, or a sloppy notation for what's really meant.

Comment: What I know is g'(x) = Lim (g(x+h)-g(x))/h
But Lim (g(x+h)-g(x))/h is not Lim (g(x+h)-g(x))/Lim h , becase Lim h =0

Comment: The substitution of eq2 into eq1 seems unjustified

Comment: @Angelo: Adding color and space is a waste of an edit. If you can't format it properly, then leave it alone for those who know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems in what you write. There isn't a single problem, there are multiple problems. Here's three of them.

1. Your step from Line 2 to Line 3 is incorrect. You got from
   $$g'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
   to
   $$g'(x)\lim_{h\to 0} h = \lim_{h\to 0}(g(x+h)-g(x)).$$
   This step is not reversible. You seem to be using that the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits... but that is only valid of the limit of the denominator is **not** zero... which is not the case here.  The second equality holds, but is not reversible (you can't go from Line 3 to Line 2). Line 3 is really trivial when you look at it closely: it just says that $0=0$. Replace $g'(x)$ with $17$, and it still holds. Replace $g'(x)$ with $2g'(x)$ and it still holds... and the substitution you would try later (which is invalid anyway, see below) would give you an extra factor of $2$ that would mess up your calculations...
2. You are trying to substitute Equation 2 into Equation 1. But Equation 2 is
   $$\lim_{h\to 0}g(x+h) =g'(x)\lim_{h\to 0}h + g(x). \tag{Eq 2}$$
   You are instead substituting $g'(x)\lim_{h\to 0}h + g(x)$ for $g(x+h)$. But that is not valid; you can't just ignore the $\lim_{h\to 0}$ on the left hand side of Eq 2, because in general it is **not** true that $g(x+h) = g'(x)\lim_{h\to 0}h + g(x)$. The left hand side depends on both $x$ and $h$, while the right hand side is just $g(x)$. So you are not even in a position to make that substitution.
3. The reason you can't do the substitution is also the reason why your manipulation *after* the substitution is invalid. You have a limit, and are trying to "add" a limit inside the limit to justify the substitution. And later, you have a limit inside a limit and you are converting that into a single limit. Neither is in general true.  You need to keep the limit variables separate. If you were actually able to do your substitution, it should really look like
   $$\begin{align}
   (f(g(x)))'&=\lim _{h\to 0}
   \frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}\\
   &=\lim _{h\to 0} \frac{f(g'(x)\cdot\left(\lim_{k\to 0}k\right) + g(x))-f(g(x))}{h}
   \end{align}$$
   and this is not the same thing as
   $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(g'(x)\cdot h + g(x))-f(g(x))}{h}$$
   which is what you claimed.
   For instance, suppose you have
   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+x}.$$
   You are saying that I could consider this as
   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+\lim_{x\to 0}x}$$
   to make the first substitution, and something similar in the other direction to convert it back to a single limit. But replace the limit-inside-the-limit with $\lim_{y\to 0}y$ to see what this does not work: compare
   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+\lim_{y\to 0}y} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+0} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x} = 1$$
   with
   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
   So you can't just convert what you actually have to what you claim you get. That step is invalid both coming and going.

Comment: Good job making sense of it. It's easy to see why it's wrong; much harder to say why it's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

This is mathematically illiterate, I'm afraid. The line
$$g'(x) \lim_{h\to 0} h = \lim _{h\to 0} g(x+h)-g(x)$$
is true, but only because $\lim_{h\to 0} h$ and $\lim _{h\to 0} g(x+h)-g(x)$ are both zero. So the conclusion
$$\lim _{h\to 0} g(x+h) = g'(x)\lim _{h\to 0} h + \lim _{h\to 0} g(x)$$
is also true, but only because it reduces to $g(x)=g(x)$. You can't actually *deduce* anything from it.

Comment: Yes, the first equation you quote would also be true with any number replacing $g'(x)$, so you can't possibly be deducing anything about $g'(x)$ by manipulating it.